# Why am I getting these weird results when editing the image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, core-graphics

I'm trying to do something very simple:

1) Draw a UIImage into a CG bitmap context

2) Get a pointer to the data of the image

3) iterate over all pixels and just set all R G B components to 0 and alpha to 255. The result should appear pure black.

---

**This is the original image I am using. 200 x 40 pixels, PNG-24 ARGB premultiplied alpha (All alpha values == 255):**

[image: original]

---

**This is the result (screenshot from Simulator), when I do not modify the pixels. Looks good:**

[image: unmodified result]

---

**This is the result, when I do the modifications! It looks like if the modification was incomplete.** But the for-loops went over EVERY single pixel. The counter proves it: Console reports modifiedPixels = 8000 which is exactly 200 x 40 pixels. It looks always exactly the same.

[image: modified result]

Note: The PNG image I use has no alpha < 255. So no transparent pixels.

---

**This is how I create the context. Nothing special...**

```
int bitmapBytesPerRow = (width * 4);
int bitmapByteCount = (bitmapBytesPerRow * imageHeight);

colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

bitmapData = malloc(bitmapByteCount);
bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,
                width,
                height,
                8, // bits per component
                bitmapBytesPerRow,
                colorSpace,
                CGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
```

---

**Next, I draw the image into that `bitmapContext`, and obtain the data like this:**

```
void *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext);
```

---

**This is the code which iterates over the pixels to modify them:**

```
size_t bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

NSInteger modifiedPixels = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        long int offset = bytesPerRow * y + 4 * x;

        // ARGB
        unsigned char alpha = data[offset];
        unsigned char red = data[offset+1];
        unsigned char green = data[offset+2];
        unsigned char blue = data[offset+3];

        data[offset] = 255;
        data[offset+1] = 0;
        data[offset+2] = 0;
        data[offset+3] = 0;

        modifiedPixels++;
    }
}
```

---

**When done, I obtain a new UIImage from the bitmap context and display it in a UIImageView, to see the result:**

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

---

## Question:

What am I doing wrong?

Is this happening because I modify the data while iterating over it? Must I duplicate it?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code? It's setting everything to 255, which should turn up as white.

Comment: Yes, right code. I just forgot to edit these values here. Previously I tried to make the image white, but the example image was hard to see here on the white background. So I made it black.

Comment: the code is using blank memory from malloc(), but the example is pre-populated with an image, i'm wondering if the image isn't in the exact format you think it is

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope it's clear now. The malloc() is just for creating the context. Then the image gets drawn into it, and then I obtain the data pointer from the context.

Comment: sounds like a padding problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(bitmapContext) to get bytesPerRow instead getting from image (image has only 3 bytes per pixels if it hasn't alpha informations)

Answer (score 1):

Might you're getting wrong height or width.... and by the way 240x40=9600 not 8000 so that's for sure that you're not iterating over each and every pixel.

Comment: Damn, this is a typo in my question. It is 200 x 40.